# Possible to do this wiring for 2 speaker enclosures

Tags: amplifier, audio, circuit-design

(See update below the original question)

---

(Original question)

Hello, could anyone tell me if it's possible to wire BT receiver, 2 amplifiers, 4 Full range speakers and 2 subs like this?

[image: Hifi setup]

---

(Update after seeing [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/418906))

I've decided to use this setup instead:

[image: Updated design]

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. Will it do what you want? Not a clue.

Comment: What concerns do you have?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Comment: Well a more specific question would be if i can input a mono signal to a stereo input amplifier, lookinh thru the comments/answers it seems so

Comment: To avoid the confusion about your input voltage, label the wires only + and - and place the "24V" in the space between them.  You may find you need a signal amplifier/splitter between the decoder and each amplifier depending on their input impedance, since you're splitting the signal 6 ways.  Subwoofers tend to cause huge input current surges, so you may want some huge decoupling capacitors.  If the power draw of your BT decoder is significant it may be better to use a dedicated 12V supply rather than running it from the 24V bus.

Comment: @DavidHožič - Hi, I've "rolled back" to the original version of your question, and then added your chosen design as an update at the bottom. That's because (a) on Stack Exchange sites, we don't put "solved" in the title to indicate that further answers aren't required, and (b) by erasing the original schematic, it makes the (currently 1) answer invalid, since that refers to the original schematic (which you removed). I hope this explanation is clear. Feel free to add a comment addressed to me, if you have questions about this. Also see the [tour] and [help] to read more about the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you have shown, in theory. In practice, there are a few missing specs like a 400W split 48V dc power supply.

Doubling the power with a tandem operation good but is only 3dB and is not a lot in terms of relative loudness.  It may be just enough to satisfy your need to rattle the walls or operate in a theatre.

The only detail left out is will your +-24V supply have enough power for 2 subs > 15A = 400W/48V *<75%.

Usually, for higher power speaker impedance and supply voltages are doubled to 16 Ohms so that current losses do not rise and get twice the power with better efficiency.

Now that I've made enough assumptions for you, why not tell us why you are suggesting this redundancy with a shared +/-24V dc.

I would suggest +/-48V with a single amp and 4 sets of speakers

Comment: Well my planned PSU is a 24v 400w one, it claims it's  from 0A to 16.7A so just a bit above 400w. This is my graduation project so I don't imagine it blasting at max volume

Comment: That sounds OK What is the ripple voltage? Is it a class D or E audio amp. Will that create more ripple?

Comment: PSU (Don't see a ripple voltage spec, 24V 400w) https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32877312740.html?spm=a2g0n.wishlist-amp.item.32877312740&aff_trace_key=&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=8656amp-zn8-el-1SCsVzZJbGwVsHA1548458341886 and the Amplifier: https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32574627375.html?spm=a2g0n.orderlist-amp.item.32574627375&aff_trace_key=&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=1759amp-zn8-el-1SCsVzZJbGwVsHA1548458543962

Comment: You may need to add a filter below ripple frequency rated for noise free audio but it depends on type of Amp

Comment: Like a solid filter capacitor? The BT decoder has that.